# Watin behaviour in debug mode is different than in normal mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, automation, watin, ui-automation

Im testing the WatiN library using this simple code:

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.de"))
{
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");        
    Button btn1 = browser.Button(Find.ById("gbqfba"));
    btn1.Click();
    while (!browser.ContainsText("watin.org"))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 500 );
        btn1.Click();
    }
}
```

Anyway it works fine when i run it in debug mode having a breakpoint somewhere, but as soon as i run in release mode it types the desired text but the button doesnt seem to be clicked, so i have the search field with the text in it, and i dont get any search results.

Any known issues about this? any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a WatiN newbie, too, and it took me a while before I got this to work. First, read this solution:

[WatiN clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215326/watin-clicking-a-button/12215875#12215875)

You might have to try different ways of implementing the solution to get it to work for you. For example:

First I put the line

```
browserInstance.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus(); // set focus befor u click
```

before the "click" action, but that worked only in Debug mode (My code didn't work at all before, so getting it to work in Debug mode was progress).

Then I put the line before **each** item to get it to work in Run mode:

```
browserInstance = new IE(@"http://www.google.com");

TextField criteria = browserInstance.TextField(tf => tf.Name == "q");

browserInstance.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus(); // set focus befor u click
criteria.TypeText("Come Jam With Us");

browserInstance.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus(); // set focus befor u click
browserInstance.Button(Find.ById("gbqfb")).Click();
```

I'm not sure why this works, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert a wait in your code till everything is loaded, then you will be able to find controls.

It works in debug mode **because**, while debugging with breakpoints it get time things to be fully loaded.

Comment: Sounds logical but its not the isseue i added a sleep inside (c edited question) its not solving the problem.

Comment: place it before browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");

Comment: This doesnt make any sense,, the typing part works, the problem is with the click, but thank you anyway

Comment: I have similar issues that Thread Sleeps don't solve neither. WatiN is often providing inconsistent results... seems unreliable.