# WatiN clicking a button

Tags: c#, watin

I'm learning the WatiN API and I got to a problem.

I use the WatiN api with the `WebBrowser` object/control and it work great for most part.
im trying to do a search in google with the API but the Button doesn't click as it should.

I'm even using the same code from WatiN site (with small difference):
my code:

```
//need to use a thread to work with the WebBrowser object
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;

    using (IE browser = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance))
    {
         browser.GoTo("http://www.google.co.il");
         browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Value = " woowow";
         browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
    }
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

I can set the text that I'm adding but, the button `"btnG"` doesn't get clicked.

When i used this code without the `WebBrowser` object/control the code works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found the problem.

i needed to change focus to the site.

this line of code works:

```
 browser.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus();
```

so now the code look like this:

```
Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;

            browser = new IE(webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance);

                browser.GoTo("http://www.google.co.il");
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Value = " woowow";

                browser.NativeDocument.Body.SetFocus(); // set focus befor u click

                browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();


        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

Comment: Wonderful. I was testing the same thing and your answer helped me!